# why my output file of python script is empty

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

i am creating a python script to record the screen of desktop.

In this i am taking only the selected area by the user and only record the selected area and convert it into a video file.

but while doing this the output of the script is a empty video file(0 bytes)

can anybody tell me where am i doing wrong. As it was working fine without the `bbox(x1,x2,y1,y2)`.

here is the code:
**EDIT:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk ,FLAT
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab, ImageEnhance
import cv2
import numpy as np
import threading
filename="test.avi"
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
frame_rate = 10
root = tk.Tk()


def show_image(image):
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    tk.Label(win, image=win.image).pack()
    win.grab_set()
    win.wait_window(win)

def area_sel():
    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0
    roi_image = None

    def on_mouse_down(event):
        nonlocal x1, y1
        x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
        canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1, y1, outline='red', tag='roi')

    def on_mouse_move(event):
        nonlocal roi_image, x2, y2
        x2, y2 = event.x, event.y
        canvas.delete('roi-image') 
        roi_image = image.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2)) 
        canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(roi_image)
        canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=canvas.image, tag=('roi-image'), anchor='nw')
        canvas.coords('roi', x1, y1, x2, y2)
        canvas.lift('roi') 

    root.withdraw()  
    image = ImageGrab.grab()  
    bgimage = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image).enhance(0.3)  
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
    win.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(win, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgimage)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tkimage, anchor='nw', tag='images')
    win.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_mouse_down)
    win.bind('<B1-Motion>', on_mouse_move)
    win.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e: win.destroy())
    win.focus_force()
    win.grab_set()
    win.wait_window(win)
    root.deiconify()  

    if roi_image:
        region = x1, y1, x2, y2

        start_recording(region) #calling main function to record screen
        return region


def recording_screen(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    global recording
    recording = True

    while recording:

        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        frame=np.array(img) # for recording
        out.write(cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))

out = cv2.VideoWriter() 
def start_recording(region):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = region
    if not out.isOpened():

            out.open(filename,fourcc, frame_rate,(x2-x1,y2-y1))
    threading.Thread(target=recording_screen, args=region, daemon=True).start()

def stop_recording():
    global recording
    recording = False
    out.release()

sel_area = ttk.Button(root, text='select area to Record', width=30, command=area_sel)
sel_area.grid(row=0, column=0)

stp_rec = ttk.Button(root, text='Stop Recording', width=30, command=stop_recording)
stp_rec.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try not use link to your code.Just add it in your post.

Comment: Make sure the value of the `video_size` is the same as the selected area's size.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf i cannot as the area is selected by the user and not me.

Comment: After the area is selected by the user, assign the value to `video_size` and then initialize the `cv2.VideoWriter`

Comment: Have you verified that `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2` are the values you're assuming they are inside `recording_screen`?

Comment: I could be a codec issue. H.264 is encoder is not natively supported by OpenCV. Have you tried other codec like: `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')`? There is another suspicious issue that we can't see from the code you have posted: What are the values of `bbox` in `video_size =bbox` and the value of `VIDEO_SIZE`?

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf i think the `(video_size) in cv2.VideoWriter` is accperting only two values `(height,weigth)` only and i am giving   `x1,x2,y1,y2`

Comment: Yes, it accepts `(h,w)`. Try passing `(y2-y1,x2-x1)`, and make sure `y2 > y1` and `x2 > x1`.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf still not working giving errors as y2 is not defined (code updated in the question)

Comment: After the area is selected by the user, verify the values of `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2`. 
Also make sure the selected frame size is equal to `(y2-y1,x2-x1)` .

Comment: Whatever frame size you pass to the `cv2.VideoWriter`, you need to write the frame of the same size.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf tried using return the value of (y2-y1,x2-x1) but giving errors as m in not defined. it is better if you can give your answer in answer section. (question updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ImageGrab` which is macOS and Windows only, so I can't test your complete code on my setup.

The problem in your code is you have coupled the area selection and video recording. Once the area is selected and you have `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2`. Return these values. Initialize the `cv2.VideoWriter` the first time.

What you can try now is use the arguments pass to `start_recording((x1, y1, x2, y2))`.

```
def start_recording(region):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = region
    if not out.isOpened():

        out.open(filename,fourcc, frame_rate,(y2-y1,x2-x1)) #given x2 > x1, y2 > y1
    threading.Thread(target=recording_screen, args=region, daemon=True).start()
```

**EDIT:**

The issue was wrong shape passed in the following call.

```
out.open(filename,fourcc, frame_rate,(y2-y1,x2-x1))
```

The `Size` value passed is `(y2-y1,x2-x1)` i.e `(height, width)` . However, the constructor expects `(width, height)`. See doc [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d50/classcv_1_1Size__.html#a45c97e9a4930d73fde11c2acc5f371ac).

Also, the `img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))` returns an [RGB image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/2.9.0.dev1/reference/ImageGrab.html#PIL.ImageGrab.PIL.ImageGrab.grab). But `out.write(frame)` expects a [BGR image](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#a30ebbc09c122332f62bd706b43f02a98). It can be fixed as:

```
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
frame = np.array(img)
out.write(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
```

Comment: You `return region`before `start_recording(region)`. Also, the `region = print(x1, y1, x2, y2)` call returns `None`. It should be `region = x1, y1, x2, y2`. I thought these were deliberate and so I mentioned them here.

Comment: its working but the quality is poor. is there any to solve that.

Comment: How do you define quality?

Comment: the video is sort of blur as when i record it with full screen its more clear.

Comment: If you are viewing a cropped video as full screen, the video will be stretched hence more pixelated.

Comment: If you are viewing using VLC, go to Video tab and uncheck always fit to windows. This will display the video in its original size.